# Sorting an element of class and finding different elements in class

Tags: c++, class, sorting, object

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class Lek{
    private:
        int sifra;
        string ime;
        string proizvoditel;
        int cena;
        int kolicina;
    public:
        Lek(){

        }
        void postavuvanje(int s, string i, string p, int c, int k){
            sifra = s;
            ime = i;
            proizvoditel = p;
            cena = c;
            kolicina = k;
        }

        int vratiSifra(){
            return sifra;
        }

        string vratiIme(){
            return ime;
        }

        string vratiProizvoditel(){
            return proizvoditel;
        }

        int vratiCena(){
            return cena;
        }

        int vratiKolicina(){
            return kolicina;
        }

        void pecati(){
            cout << sifra << " " << ime << " " << proizvoditel << " " << cena << " " << kolicina << endl;
        }
};

int main(){
    Lek Apteka[100];
    int n;
    cout << "Vnesi go brojot na lekovi" << endl;
    cin >> n;
    int sifra;
    string ime;
    string proizvoditel;
    int cena;
    int kolicina;

    // here we are inputting the values for the array of objects.
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        cin >> sifra;
        cin >> ime;
        cin >> proizvoditel;
        cin >> cena;
        cin >> kolicina;
        Apteka[i].postavuvanje(sifra, ime, proizvoditel, cena, kolicina);
    }

    // this is part to find the name of the element with the lowest price.
    int najmala_cena = Apteka[0].vratiCena();
    int index = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i < n; i++){
        if(Apteka[i].vratiCena() < najmala_cena){
            najmala_cena = Apteka[i].vratiCena();
            index = i;
        }
    }

    cout << Apteka[index].vratiIme() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I have managed to solve the problem of finding the element with lowest price. However, I am having trouble sorting the elements by price (cena). Also, I have to find all elements who have 'proizvoditel' "X" and find how many different names (ime) does it have.

For sorting the elements by price (cena) I think it's self-explanatory. But since my English isn't that good with the second problem, here is basically a quick example.

Let's say we have the following input by user:

```
1
PillX
HospitalY
125
2

2
PillY
HospitalY
225
4

3
PillZ
HospitalY
590
1

4
PillX
HospitalY
125
8
```

So, basically, those are the attributes of 4 objects of the class and we have the same 'proizvoditel' for all the pills, called "HospitalY" and we have to find how many different pills does it have, so it has 3, since PillX already exists and is not counted the second time.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be overloading your own custom sort operator and using `std::sort` in `#include <algorithm>`:

```
bool cena_comp(const Lek &a, const Lek &b) { return a.vratiCena() < b.vratiCena(); }
```

Using it:

```
bool (*cena_comp_ptr)(const Lek &a, const Lek &b) = cena_comp;
Lek *beg = &Apteka[0], *end = &Apteka[n];
sort(beg, end, cena_comp_ptr);
```

Comment: Quick question, is there any difference of using sort or stable_sort?

Comment: @user3402189, Yes there is. In stable sort, equal elements are not moved. Example imagine a list `[... A, B, ...]`, with A and B having a different kolicena. If you use `stable_sort`, A will always come before B. If you use `sort`, the order may not be preservered

Comment: So, basically using sort() will sort the price and change the values with the current elements (the rest will stay the same)? And if we use the stable_sort the values for other stuff along with the price will be the same except the places of the whole elements will be changed?

Comment: Also, where do I place the bool cena_comp? I get errors no matter where I place it.